# 301 redirect non-www to wwww asp.net C3

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I wanted to know how to create a 301 redirect from www to non-www in ASP.net C#. I want to put this code on two pages. I want a code that will prevent looping, which I've read in couple of placed. The code should be put in the Page_Load section of each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "www to non-www" or what does that have to do with redirection... Anyway, there is no built in function to make 301 redirect, but it is pretty trivial to do manually.

```
Response.StatusCode = 301;
Response.AppendHeader("Location", "your url to redirect to");
Response.End();
```

Comment: I'd like to add (for clarification for others) that Response.Redirect() in ASP.NET only performs a 302 redirect, and that for a 301 you have to do it manually - unless you're using .NET 4.0 in which case there's Response.RedirectPermanent().

Comment: @David ah nice I didn't know they added that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try the URI Rewriting extension for IIS7 and 7.5 - it has an option that enables "canonical domains" where all requests are redirected to their www. equivalents.

Here: http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite

It works regardless of what generates your pages (so it also works for static content too).

Comment: I did it like this:

string url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

        if (url.Contains("www"))
        {
            // redirect
            Response.RedirectPermanent(url.Replace("http://www.", "http://"));

        }